# How to start tkinter.Checkbutton with button checked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Question as above, not much more I can say

```
tab2.content.append(
            Checkbutton(
                tab2,
                text="Fullscreen",
                command=lambda: settings.update({'Fullscreen': not settings['Fullscreen']})
                ).grid(row=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has issue that `None` will be appended to `tab2.content` because you append the result of `grid()`.

Use:

```py
cb = Checkbutton(tab2, text="Fullscreen", 
                 command=lambda: settings.update({'Fullscreen': not settings['Fullscreen']}))
cb.grid(row=1)
cb.select() # make it checked
tab2.content.append(cb)
```

Comment: That wasn’t my original issue, but thank you, that does fix it and whatever future issues would have like that.

Comment: There is no `select` method of Checkbutton. What do you mean?

Comment: `tkinter.Checkbutton` has `select()` function.  Do you mean `ttk.Checkbutton`?

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: `ttk` widgets use theme.